# Call url from javascript where the url is not in the same level as index.php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to call a php file through ajax. No problem so far. But my file is in a folder called application/logic. the problem is that my domain is redirected to public/ where my index.php file is. Now my js files are also in that root public/js. Now how can I reach the php files under application/logic through javascript?

```
function add_DropDown(formid){

    var arr = demountform(formid);
    var myjsonarr = JSON.stringify(arr);
    $.ajax({ 
        url:'../application/logic/admin-functions.php',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            alert(output);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you include from root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access files with an ajax request that are outside of the web root. If you can not access a file from browser address bar then you would not be able to access it from javascript too. A solution could be creating a php file in `/public` that will include or require `/application/logic/admin-functions.php`.

Comment: I created a router file, which includes and routes to the different function in my admin-functions file

Answer (score 2):

If you understand you right, you want to access a file outside your webroot folder. There are several ways to do that:

- create a virtual host for that folder (e.g. for a subdomain)
- create a softlink from your webroot to the file
- create a proxy php file in your webroot including your file